# How do you define an array to the length of a string of numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm unsure how exactly to do this. If anyone has some expert advice that would be extremely helpful!

```
#define SIZE ((int) (sizeof(digit_count)/sizeof(digit_count[0]))
#define N count

int main()
{
    int i, num, count, digit_count[N] = {0};

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   while (num != 0)
   {
      digit_count[num % 10]++;
      num /= 10;
      ++count;
   }

 for (i = 0; i < SIZE); i++)
        printf("%d occured %d times\n", i, digit_count[i]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because  `N` is *replaced* by the symbol `count` which is uninitialized and have an indeterminate value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is there a way to set the length of digit_count after determining the length of the user inputted string?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz could you elaborate on how to implement that into my code?

Comment: @legitbagel There's nothing special about your requirements -- this is the most typical way it's used. You can just read almost any article on how to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc`:

```
int main()
{
   int base = 10;
   int num, *digit_count;

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   digit_count = malloc (base * sizeof (int));
   if (!digit_count)
       return -1;

   while (num != 0)
   {
      digit_count[num % base]++;
      num /= base;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < base); i++)
        printf("%d occurred %d times\n", i, digit_count[i]);

   free(digit_count);
   return 0;
}
```

Since there are always ten digits, there's no reason to use dynamic memory allocation here, but the same pattern used here would work just as well if the number of entries you needed to allocate changed at run time. You could make `base` change at run time and the program would still work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your particular problem

For this particular case, you don't need an array of as many elements as the number has digits, you need an array of 10 elements:

```
int digit_count[10] = { 0 };

...

    // num % 10 is never larger than 9.
    digit_count[num % 10]++;
```

By the way, it would be better to use an `unsigned int num` and `"%u"` in the `scanf` because this will still misbehave for negative numbers, when `num % 10` is negative (for C99 and later) or has an unspecified value (older C).

#### Arrays long enough to hold the digits of a number

In the event that one day you need an array large enough to hold all individual digits of a number, my advice is to use the upper bound; that is to say: enough space to hold the longest number the data type can hold. An approximation that holds beyond megabit integers (i.e., for everything you'll ever encounter) is

```
#define MAX_DIGITS10(type) (2 + sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT * 643L / 2136)

...

int digits[MAX_DIGITS10(int)];
```

This works because `643L / 2136` is a decent approximation of log<sub>10</sub>(2).

The approach is shamelessly lifted from GNU's libstdc++, which uses

```
#define __glibcxx_max_digits10(T) \
  (2 + (T) * 643L / 2136)
```

in the C++ standard library header `<limits>`.

#### Arrays of variable length

In the event that you one day need an array of truly variable length, you have to calculate the length before allocating the array. Once you have calculated the length, C99 and later, which have VLAs (variable-length arrays), allow you to simply write

```
size_t calculated_length = calculate_length();
int vla[calculated_length] = { 0 };

// vla goes out of scope like normal arrays; no cleanup necessary
```

Before C89, you would have to use `malloc` (or `calloc`) and `free`:

```
size_t calculated_length = calculate_length();

int *heap_array = calloc(calculated_length, sizeof(int));
// or:
int *heap_array = malloc(calculated_length * sizeof(int));

// and when you're done:

free(heap_array);
```

Note that with `malloc` it's up to you to check that `calculated_length * sizeof(int)` does not overflow (most `calloc` implementations do that internally), and that `calloc` zero-initializes the memory while `malloc` does not. This makes `calloc` a little slower, naturally, but where that is not a problem, my advice is to prefer it over `malloc`.

VLAs are arguably superior when the array does not need to live beyond the scope in which it is declared, but you should be aware that you cannot use VLAs that are larger than the thread stack, which is usually limited to anything between one and a few megabytes. For large arrays, it is necessary to use the *alloc functions.